# ASP classic read include into variable like php

Tags: php, asp-classic

In php the code is this

```
ob_start();
require('order-mail-view.php');
$body = ob_get_clean();
```

Is there an equalivement in classic asp ? Included file should be processed first.

Comment: What does `order-mail-view.php` do can you include the code?

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of `require` in Classic ASP is `#include` SSI directive;

```vb
<% 
Dim body
Call ob_start() 
%>
<!-- #include file="order-mail-view.asp" -->
<% 
body = ob_get_clean()
%>
```

Comment: @Parhs isnt that what `body` is?

Comment: @Parhs `#include` just allows you to include server-side script from another physical file. If you structure the file in functions then you have access to the functions in the main page. That way you can return what you like, in that regard `require` is no different. It depends on what you have in `order-mail-view.asp`.

Comment: @Parhs Another point if you declare a variable say `Dim body` in your main page and as long as the scope doesn't change you can manipulate that variable inside the SSI file to your hearts content.

Comment: ob_start() and ob_get_clean() are php functions. actually body contains the content of order-mail-view.php  a html page with output from main php page.

Comment: @Parhs In which case the `order-mail-view.php` is setting `body` so if you mimic that in the Classic ASP equivalent you will get the same result. The only way I can think of outputting the HTML would be as a string something like `body = "<html>...</html>"` but that would that can be quite cumbersome to maintain.